# How to make a three column table into a two column table for mobile

Tags: html, css, html-table, responsive

I need to make a three-column table into a two-column table on mobile. This should support IE. It currently DOES go to two-column when resizing the viewport but the third item in the row behaves strange and floats either left or right and then has a missing slot. I want it to look more like it does when I use flex or grid and to have some continuity. I want to change the code to flexbox but am unsure about IE support. Does anyone know how I can do this?

```css
.topcolumn {
    float: left;
     padding: 10px;
  /*width: 250px;*/
 } 

/* Create two equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
     padding: 10px;
  width:300px;
 }

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row{
    display: table;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<!-- New Row Start -->
<div class="row">
<div class="column"><br>
<div class="name">Don Abrams, M.D.</div>
<div class="BoardTitle">Vice President, Graduate Medical Education</div>
</div>
<!-- BREAK --->
<div class="column"><br>
<div class="name">Charles Albrecht, M.D.</div>
<div class="BoardTitle">Chief Quality Officer</div>
</div>
<!-- BREAK --->
<div class="column"><br>
<div class="name">Debra Morton</div>
<div class="BoardTitle">Interim Chief Nursing Officer<br>
</div>
</div>
<!-- BREAK --->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go ahead and use flexbox for this issue. [According to the MDN you should be okay.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Backwards_Compatibility_of_Flexbox) From the website:

> Internet Explorer 10, which implemented the display: flexbox version of the specification with the -ms- prefix.
>
> Note also that Internet Explorer 11 supports the modern display: flex specification however it has a number of bugs in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge and experience, it's always with use of media queries.

But! to make it easier in the long run (tricky when first learning), I would consider looking into laying out components in a grid format. This will enable you to change the dimensions of the grid according to the different product resolutions. Good Luck!

Example of media query:

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {}

potentially useful resource also: [https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/#:~:text=Combining%20media%20query%20expressions,that%20are%20600%2D400px%20wide](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width/#:%7E:text=Combining%20media%20query%20expressions,that%20are%20600%2D400px%20wide).

Comment: I know grid very well but I work for a hospital and need to support IE. Grid is not supported by IE.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't read the whole question. Something I learned now to practice :)